# How can I return a string from callback?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, callback

I have a method

```
 private string MakeRequest
```

which has returned me a string earlier, but now  I have in this method an async operation.

```
request.BeginGetRequestStream(GetRequestStreamCallback, request);

 private void GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
    {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;

        // End the operation
        var postStream = request.EndGetRequestStream(asynchronousResult);

        // Convert the string into a byte array.
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(request.Connection);

        // Write to the request stream.
        postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, request.Connection.Length);
        postStream.Close();

        // Start the asynchronous operation to get the response
        request.BeginGetResponse(GetResponseCallback, request);
    }

    private static void GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
    {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;

        // End the operation
        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);
        var streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream();
        using (var streamRead = new StreamReader(streamResponse))
        {
            var responseString = streamRead.ReadToEnd();
            var trimResponseString = responseString.Trim(); // I need this string to return from MakeRequest
            // Close the stream object
            streamResponse.Close();
            streamRead.Close();

            // Release the HttpWebResponse
            response.Close();
            allDone.Set();
        }
    }
```

How can I return the string from last callback to MakeRequest?

Comment: Have you considered using Tasks instead? `WebRequest.GetRequestStreamAsync` returns a Task, you can await that. Not sure what you are calling from but if its WPF, WinForms, asp.net your entry can be marked as `async` with return of some form of `Task`. You can then await the `GetRequestStreamAsync`

Comment: @Igor, how exactly should I do? I have never done it before.

Comment: What version of .NET are you using? There are much easier ways to do this nowadays.

Comment: @JLRishe .NET 4.5

Comment: @Ekaterina - what is your entry point (ie. what are you calling this from)? Console app, wpf, winforms, mvc, asp.net, something else?

Comment: @Igor Console application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using .NET 4.5, you can take advantage of the `Task`-based methods in `WebRequest`:

```
public async Task<string> MakeRequest()
{
    var request = WebRequest.Create(url);

    var postStream = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync();

    // Convert the string into a byte array.
    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(request.Connection);

    // Write to the request stream.
    postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, request.Connection.Length);
    postStream.Close();

    var response = (HttpWebResponse)(await request.GetResponseAsync());
    var streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream();

    using (var streamRead = new StreamReader(streamResponse))
    {
        var responseString = streamRead.ReadToEnd();
        var trimResponseString = responseString.Trim(); // I need this string to return from MakeRequest
        // Close the stream object
        streamResponse.Close();
        streamRead.Close();

        // Release the HttpWebResponse
        response.Close();
        allDone.Set();

        return trimResponseString;
    }
}
```

If you're calling this from a context that isn't itself asynchronous, you can call this method and then synchronously await the result:

```
string result = MakeRequest().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Comment: But HttpWebResponse is not awaitable
var response = await (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponseAsync();

Comment: @Ekaterina Sorry, needed to rearrange the parentheses. Please see my update.